# how to stop this javax.xml.ws.Endpoint service

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

i have like this below code in order to start to publish wsdl

```
    package my.mimos.stp.MelodyWS.webservice;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;



public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/Melody/MelodyService", new MelodyWS());

        System.out.println("Melody service is ready");

    }

}
```

what should i do if i want to stop that service? i have a changes in MelodyWS and would like to republish it.

Answer (score 7):

You have to keep a reference on the Endpoint object and call `stop()` method on it:

```
Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new MelodyWS());
ep.publish("http://localhost:8081/Melody/MelodyService");
..
ep.stop();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting an error: "Address already in use: bind". I believe it's because of the "publish()" method. Any tips how to get around that?

Comment: @BustedSanta Stopping of the service does not occur immediately. When `ep.stop()` finishes, the port that you were previously bound to (in this example, 8081) should be free. You can check that with the telnet command (e.g. `telnet localhost 8081`). Only after the port is free, you can republish the service.